# Website hosted on my laptop: IP address redirects to localhost for all users (local and network)

Tags: redirect, localhost

I'm using MAMP to host my Joomla website on my Macbook.  I've been developing it for a while and showing a few people by giving them my ip address.  Recently we got the domain name [name removed by request], and I set up the forwarding to point to my IP.  Now when anyone tries to visit the site via domain name or my ip they get re-directed to localhost.

What could be causing this?  I've seen a few related questions, but their solutions didn't work for me or the situation was different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it get redirected to localhost on port 8888

most likely an error in your apache host configuration

Comment: Yes, I changed "localhost" to my ip under "domain name" in my apache configuration, and now it works.  It's just strange because it was "localhost" for the longest time but didn't give me that problem.